# be stuck when trying to install gradle via scoop command

Tags: gradle

I wanna install gradle on my pc:
I found in `https://gradle.org/install/`

```
scoop install gradle
```

- Scoop is a command-line installer for Windows inspired by Homebrew.

So I have to install scoop first of all, I found this command:

```
 iex (new-object net.webclient).downloadstring('https://get.scoop.sh')
```

which has to be executed on Windows Powershell

After fixing the proxy authentication, I executed the previous  command, then I reexecuted it again a message is displayed for me:

```
Scoop is already installed. Run 'scoop update' to get the latest version.
```

I said, all is ok now let's execute `scoop install gradle`
but what I get is:

```
scoop : Le terme «scoop» n'est pas reconnu comme nom d'applet de commande, 

fonction, fichier de script ou programme
exécutable. Vérifiez l'orthographe du nom, ou si un chemin d'accès existe, vérifiez que le chemin d'accès est correct
et réessayez.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ scoop install gradle
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (scoop:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Really, I am stuck, I don't know what to do

Comment: you need to initiate another cmd window to be able to work with scoop, that's how windows works

Answer (score 2):

delete c:/users/yourname/scoop folder and try again